# How can I use Django intcomma in integerfield

Tags: python, django

I'd like to separate numerical values in the form with a comma in my Django project.
Then I found the documentation below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/humanize/

I thought that I can use 'intcomma' for my purpose. So I added "django.contrib.humanize" to my INSTALLED_APPS setting. And put {% load humanize %} in a template.

When I use 'intcomma' like below, it worked.

```
{{ 999999|intcomma }} # 999,999
```

But It did not work for integer form like below:

```
{{ form.numbers|intcomma }} # did not work.
```

A code was displayed to html instead of numbers like this:

```
<input type="number" name="int_sample" value="100000" id="id_int_sample"
```

My Django version is 2.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

## Formatting the *value* of an `IntegerField`

You access the *value* of an `IntegerField` with the **`.value`** attribute, so:

```
{{ form.numbers.value|intcomma }}
```

Note that this is the *value* set to the `Form` when you construct it. For example through `initial={..}` or the value that corresponds to the `instance=...` you pass to the field. If you for example in th form change the value, the content will *not* change.

## Generating an `<input>` with number formatting

In case we want the `<input>` element itself to format the number separated with comma's, we will need some HTML/JavaScript. Since Django basically only renders a webpage. How the webpage behaves in the browser is not really the responsibility of Django.

We can for example use the following approach:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function commas(input){
   input.value = Number(input.value).toLocaleString();
}
</script>
{{ form.numbers }}
```

And the `Form` should then make sure the `commas` function is invoked:

```
SomeForm(forms.Form):
    numbers = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onclick':'commas(self)'})
    )
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick answer, thank you so much!

I added ".value" attribute and a number was displayed that separated by commas.But it was not in the input field.

I expected that I could edit the number in the input field. Is it possible to edit the number in a input field?

Comment: @Hiro: No that is not possible. The filter is simply a filter that takes a number and formats it that way. You will need to use some HTML/CSS/JavaScript for this type of formatting.

Comment: @Hiro: see edit. Although it might needs some extra scaffolding.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. Now I understand what should i do. I will try to implement as you said to me. Thank you so much.